# Google Chrome Extension GetElementById triggers without being clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I have the following in my popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("data").addEventListener("click", startHandler);
    document.getElementById("example1").addEventListener("click", exampleFunc(1));
    document.getElementById("example2").addEventListener("click", exampleFunc(2));
    document.getElementById("example3").addEventListener("click", exampleFunc(3));

  });
```

and my popup.hmtl looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="data">Example Stack Overflow Problem</button>
    <button disabled id="example1">N/A</button>
    <button disabled id="example2">N/A</button>
    <button disabled id="example3">N/A</button>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

So the problem I have is that:

If I click the id = "data" button , startHandler, exampleFunc(1), exampleFunc(2) and exampleFunc(3) run. I would just like startHandler to Run.

Does anyone know why this is?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: `addEventListener` expects a reference to the handler function, you're calling that function instead.

Comment: Hi Teemu, sorry I'm not sure I follow - could you give me an example? (I'm a noob)

Comment: `.addEventListener("click", function () {exampleFunc(1);})` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Teemu. I tried this earlier, but then none of the functions ran. I just realised that because the first function doesn't take an argument, it needs to be written differently. working now :)